# Changing values of objects in std vector c++

Tags: c++, c++17, stdvector

I noticed that I am not able to change values of objects stored inside a `std::vector` or a `std::map`. The output of the code below gives `"0"` as a result of the `toggle()` function call in both cases. This behavior is not present while using the object directly, outside of the vector. Am I missing something about `std::vector` or similar containers? How do we properly store objects in containers and keep the ability to change their values?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

class OtherThing{
public:
void addElement(std::function<int()> func){
    this->myfuncs.push_back(func);
}
void toggle(){
    std::cout << "toggle .. " << this->myfuncs[0]() << std::endl;
}
private:
std::vector<std::function<int()>> myfuncs; 
};

class Thing: public OtherThing{
public:
Thing(){
    std::function<int()> myfunc= [this]()->int{
        std::cout << "from lambda " << this->value << std::endl;
        return this->value;
        };
    this->addElement(myfunc);
    }
void setValue(int value){
    this->value = value;
}
int getValue(){
    return this->value;
}
private:
int value;
};


int main() {
    // container for things 
    std::vector<Thing> mythings;
    // a thing
    Thing a;
    
    mythings.push_back(a);
    
    mythings[0].setValue(666);
    
    mythings[0].toggle();
    mythings[0].setValue(999);
    mythings[0].toggle();
    return 0;
}
```

output :

```
clang++-7 -pthread -std=c++17 -o main main.cpp
./main
toggle .. from lambda 0
0
toggle .. from lambda 0
0
```

Comment: You create `Thing a;`, then copy that into mythings.  But the copy still refers to `a`, not `mythings[0]` in the lambda stored in `myfuncs`.

Comment: Thanks @Eljay now it works fine. but how to avoid using "new" and push_back directly a pointer to a ? 
    
    std::vector<Thing*> mythings;
    // a thing
    Thing* a = new Thing();

Comment: I'd do it by not passing in a lambda with a closure on the `this`, rather pass in the `this` as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`push_back(a)` makes a *copy* of `a`. `mythings[0]` returns a reference to that copy. As such, anything done to modify the members of `mythings[0]` will not be reflected in `a`, and vice versa.

However, when `a` is copied by `push_back()`, `Thing`'s compiler-generated copy constructor will copy the `myfuncs` vector as-is, and so the lambda that `a`'s constructor had stored in that vector is also copied as-is. That lambda had captured a `this` pointer that points at `a`, not the new copy.

So, when you call `mythings[0].setValue()`, you are modifying the `value` of the copied `Thing`, but when you call `mythings[0].toggle()`, you are calling a lambda that prints the `value` of `a` - *which was never initialized in the first place*, so the output is *indeterminate* until `a.setValue()` is called.

To fix this, you need to implement your own copy constructor for `Thing` that stores its own lambda capturing the copied `Thing`'s `this` pointer, not store a copy of the earlier lambda from the `Thing` being copied from, eg:

```cpp
Thing(const Thing &src){
    value = src.value;
    std::function<int()> myfunc = [this]()->int{
        std::cout << "from copied lambda " << this->value << std::endl;
        return this->value;
    };
    this->addElement(myfunc);
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/eB42O0)

Comment: "... the output is indeterminate..." which is **undefined behavior**, so an architecture that has a memory flag indicating whether any given byte of memory has been initialized or not and will trigger a fault and abend the program when accessing that third rail.  And that's perfectly cromulent behavior in this scenario.

Comment: Practically, you should instead take a this pointer as an argument to the lambda.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying this also based on the comments. Honestly, I do not like this. Too much script just to call toggle()

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

class Thing;

class OtherThing{
public:
void addElement(std::function<int(Thing*)> func){
    this->myfuncs.push_back(func);
}
void toggle(Thing* obj){
    std::cout << "toggle .. " << this->myfuncs[0](obj) << std::endl;
}
private:
std::vector<std::function<int(Thing*)>> myfuncs; 
};

class Thing: public OtherThing{
public:
Thing(){
    std::function<int(Thing*)> myfunc= [](Thing* obj)->int{
        std::cout << "from lambda " << obj->value << std::endl;
        return obj->value;
        };
    this->addElement(myfunc);
    }
void setValue(int value){
    this->value = value;
}
int getValue(){
    return this->value;
}
private:
int value;
};


int main() {
    // container for things 
    std::vector<Thing> mythings;
    
    // a thing
    Thing a;
    
    
    // copy is here
    mythings.push_back(a);
    
    // test
    mythings[0].setValue(666);
    mythings[0].toggle(&mythings[0]);
    mythings[0].setValue(999);
    mythings[0].toggle(&mythings[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
toggle .. from lambda 666
666
toggle .. from lambda 999
999
```